# What js/css files should I bundle?

Tags: javascript, css, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

I am looking into the bundling features of ASP.NET 4.0 and am just curious what rules/practices people follow when deciding which files to bundle?

Should I group things by what they are, like put all `jQuery` files together or is it a good idea just to bundle up all files that are used in the same place?

Comment: The answer to this question is likely going to be highly subjective and come down to a matter of opinion and judgement calls, so I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @zzzzBov Fair enough, but it could still be a helpful reference I think. I've seen more subjective questions than this.

Comment: Have edited your question, as web essentials is just an extension to Visual Studio and bundling and minification is actually a part of ASP.Net 4.0

Comment: @ColinBacon Thanks, you're right web essentials is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading this tutorial on bundling and minification

[bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Personally, I like to have one css bundle and one js bundle per page.  Each bundle will only contain the files needed for that page.  Keeps the http requests and size down.

Comment: Yuck! an ASP.net Microsoft link? :P

Comment: Given this is a Microsoft asp.net question, yes.

Comment: touche! Didn't know what Web Essentials was.

Answer (score 0):

I think how to bundle your files can be largely subjective. The only thing I think most everyone would agree upon, is you should organize your files once you have more than just a few.

If you are working on a simple site and you only have a few JS files and one CSS file, I don't see a problem with putting them all in the same place.

Once you get multiple files I like to *at least* group them by type:

```
/lib/css
/lib/js
```